# How to mount a folder on amazon ec2 instance with private key using sshfs

Tags: amazon-ec2, sshfs

I am trying to mount a folder on my `amazon ec2` instance to my desktop folder using `sshfs`.

The problem is that I am not able to figure out how to give the option for private key (awskey.pem).

Normally I `ssh` using

```
ssh ec2-user@{amz-ip-address} -i {path to amzkey.pem}
```

But `sshfs` has no such options. However I saw a `-F` option and tried

```
sshfs ec2-user@{amz-ip-address}:{amz-folder}  {my mount dir} -F {path to amzkey.pem}
```

This gave me an error

> "read: Connection reset by peer"

Please let me know if anyone has tried this before.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshfs):

> If you are using non-default key names and are passing it as `-i .ssh/my_key`, this won't work. You have to use `-o IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/my_key`, with the full path to the key.

Comment: And I just confirmed that this works. +1. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: I also found that you must use full, explicit path of local folder. For instance, `~/remoteDir` did not work for me while `/home/user/remoteDir` does.

Comment: In my case the issue was with a relative path to the key. Worked ok with an absoulte path.

Answer (score 30):

Here is the command for anyone trying this in future

```
sudo sshfs {username}@{ipaddress}:{remote folder path}  {local folder path} -o IdentityFile={full path to the private key file} -o allow_other
```

Comment: What `-o allow_other` does here?

Comment: "-o allow_other" allows for non sudo access to the mounted directory. this is useful when sshfs itself needed sudo, so without "-o allow_other" you'd have to work with  su on the mounted directory for every command

Comment: I can confirm this works great and with Sublime. Thanks!